# How can I merge this Head and Body models?

Tags: modeling, objects, sculpting, topology

I have a Head model extracted from PES 2021 (let's call it head01) and a Daz Studio Genesis 3 avatar. I would like to delete the head on the avatar and change it with the one I have extracted, but the head01 is divided in different meshes for hair, face and eyes and I want to keep this structure. How can I merge the head and avatar in a seamless way that still keeps the different division of head01 untouched?

If you want to test, here are the two models:
https://mega.nz/file/PodFVa6K#TEzyDkCGwkI68uLN2fsh4IU02R-JwlCdzv-f9prjaoM

https://mega.nz/file/D9Uh0Cxb#DuyDBRPQIed0fqW9f8SRoTU6S2qaDo5NUCCPr8YIPy0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have messed with this quite a bit myself, but I don’t really have a strong answer for you. I can try out the models and see if I can do it, but it really depends.

Comment: What's wrong with connecting the new head to the neck of the base mesh (body)? You can convert the tris to quads, remove the head from the base mesh where the heads overlap, join the meshes and connect the base mesh with the new head. Smooth the mesh with the Smooth brush in Sculpt mode. Of course, editing will mess up the UV mappings and you might have to recreate them and transfer the textures.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. In the end I was able to do it in a similar way as the one suggested by Blunder without the smooth brush because of UV mapping problems.